# exception handling in ngx-socket-io angular

Tags: angular, socket.io, ngx-socket-io

In angular, `SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)` in `app.module.ts` keeps on trying to connect with localhost 8080 which is not running currently

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
    url:"http://localhost:8080/",
    options: {},
};


@NgModule({
..
imports: [
....
SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
...
]
}
```

[image]

It should be try to connect to the socket server once and stop if there is some kind of error( in my case ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED).

how to handle this exception in ngx-socket-io?
little help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by adding additional option in SocketIoConfig.

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
    url:"http://localhost:8080/",
    options: { reconnection:false},
};
```